# Use paho-mqtt on Rust

Tags: rust, mqtt

I have seen in `Crates.io` that there is a crate which already implements `MQTT`. But when trying to use the example provided in [the repo](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/47eb3eaee53a9e5f3687f9120b20d15a22a7bb9f/README.md) I got so many errors and as part of the learning process, I am considering fixing that.

after adding

```
[dependencies]
paho-mqtt = "0.7.1"
```

I tried to build using this main.rs:

```
use std::process;

extern crate paho_mqtt as mqtt;

fn main() {
    // Create a client & define connect options
    let cli = mqtt::Client::new("tcp://localhost:1883").unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        println!("Error creating the client: {:?}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    });

    let conn_opts = mqtt::ConnectOptionsBuilder::new()
        .keep_alive_interval(Duration::from_secs(20))
        .clean_session(true)
        .finalize();

    // Connect and wait for it to complete or fail
    if let Err(e) = cli.connect(conn_opts).wait() {
        println!("Unable to connect:\n\t{:?}", e);
        process::exit(1);
    }

    // Create a message and publish it
    let msg = mqtt::Message::new("test", "Hello world!");
    let tok = cli.publish(msg);

    if let Err(e) = tok.wait() {
        println!("Error sending message: {:?}", e);
    }

    // Disconnect from the broker
    let tok = cli.disconnect();
    tok.wait().unwrap();
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `Duration`
  --> src/main.rs:13:30
   |
13 |         .keep_alive_interval(Duration::from_secs(20))
   |                              ^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `Duration`

error[E0599]: no method named `wait` found for enum `std::result::Result<mqtt::ServerResponse, mqtt::MqttError>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:18:44
   |
18 |     if let Err(e) = cli.connect(conn_opts).wait() {
   |                                            ^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<mqtt::ServerResponse, mqtt::MqttError>`

error[E0061]: this function takes 3 arguments but 2 arguments were supplied
  --> src/main.rs:24:15
   |
24 |     let msg = mqtt::Message::new("test", "Hello world!");
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------  -------------- supplied 2 arguments
   |               |
   |               expected 3 arguments

error[E0599]: no method named `wait` found for enum `std::result::Result<(), mqtt::MqttError>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:27:25
   |
27 |     if let Err(e) = tok.wait() {
   |                         ^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<(), mqtt::MqttError>`

error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 0 arguments were supplied
  --> src/main.rs:32:19
   |
32 |     let tok = cli.disconnect();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^- supplied 0 arguments
   |                   |
   |                   expected 1 argument

error[E0599]: no method named `wait` found for enum `std::result::Result<(), mqtt::MqttError>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:33:9
   |
33 |     tok.wait().unwrap();
   |         ^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<(), mqtt::MqttError>`

error: aborting due to 6 previous errors
```

the error in line `13` I could solve by using `std::time::Duration`

the error in line `24` I could solve by adding the `QoS`

What are the other errors that I am missing?

Comment: Suggest you try one of the [examples](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/tree/master/examples), which are bit more complete than the snippet in the `README`.

Comment: I considered that, but when I went for [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/master/examples/sync_publish.rs), I had problems with `env_logger::init();`

Comment: and some examples like [this one](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/master/examples/async_persist_publish.rs) have the same problems and sometimes even more.

Comment: The `README` explains under [Logging](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust#logging): "*The sample applications use the enviroment log crate, `env_logger` to configure output via the `RUST_LOG` environment variable.*".  Suggest you add `env_logger` to your crate's dependencies.

Comment: I did add `log = "0.4.11"` to dependencies but I still have the same error when running `cargo build`. I have also tried `export RUST_LOG=info`

Comment: ????  [`log`](https://crates.io/crates/log) != [`env_logger`](https://crates.io/crates/env_logger).

Comment: Nice, got that one! What about the `wait` error?

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/master/examples/legacy_async_publish.rs#L6-L8.

Comment: I saw the `env_logger` reference at the `log` crate. That's why

Comment: Now I get the error  ```the trait `core::future::future::Future` is not implemented for `paho_mqtt::token::Token` ``` when I try to run `.await?` in [the newasync_publish.rs](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/master/examples/async_publish.rs), even though I can see that `Future` is implemented [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.rust/blob/47eb3eaee53a9e5f3687f9120b20d15a22a7bb9f/src/token.rs#L483). What am I missing, pls?

Comment: @ignacio Unfortunately it looks like that crate uses `futures` v0.1, while the latest is v0.3. However, you might be able to get away with using `futures::compat::Compat01As03::new(tok).await` [from the `futures` crate](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/compat/struct.Compat01As03.html).